# Rendering a dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

lets say i have an options array below

```js
options = [ { name: 'My profile' }, { name: 'Sign out' } ]

public selectOptions(showOptions: boolean) {
    this.setState({ showOptions: !showOptions })
    return options.map((option: any, index: number) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={index}
          option={option}>
          {option.name}
        <div/>
      )
    }
    )
  }
```

How can I simply render a dropdown list without using any external library. The above code does not render any divs

Comment: I think you need read this page https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag, it helps you to render a select or make a custom dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, the **only** rendering done by a class-based component is done via the return value of `render`. So what you'd do in your case is just set the state in `selectOptions`, and then in `render` you either include the options or not based on the state flag:

```
public selectOptions(showOptions: boolean) {
    this.setState({ showOptions });
    //              ^---- I removed the !, surely you should be using the flag as is?
}

public render() {
    const {showOptions} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>Any other stuff you're rendering...</div>

        {showOptions &&
            <div>
                {options.map((option: any, index: number) => {
                  return (
                    <div
                      key={index}
                      option={option}>
                      {option.name}
                    <div/>
                  )
                })}
            </div>
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

const Drop = () => {
    const options = [ { name: 'My profile' }, { name: 'Sign out' } ]
    return (
        <div><select>{
            options.map ( (opt) => {
                return (
                    <option>{opt.name}</option>
                )
        })}
        </select></div>
    )
}

export default Drop;
```

This above is displaying dropdown with your required data.

Comment: how do you get the actual dropdown to show up? I am clicking on the div with the function call but nothing is showing up.

Comment: i have just made it a component and used this component wherever dropdown was required. If you to render this dropdown on some activity then you can render it conditionally like: { showoptions && <Dropdown /> } in render method